# Android - how to save document files to Documents folder with SAF (Java)

Tags: java, android, saf, action-open-document-tree

I am having trouble with an issue saving a PDF and CSV file to the Documents folder on Android. On two devices it seems to work (Samsung Galaxy Tab S8+ and Teclast M40 Plus), but on one device (Lenovo M10 Plus FHD 2nd Gen) it does not.

I tried various solutions and libraries and **none seem to work**. None of them seem to be able to get the file path from the URI.

This is my attempt usng the pickiT library;

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d("GraphActivity", "Result OK");
        return;
    }
    Uri treeUri = data.getData();
    DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
    grantUriPermission(getPackageName(), treeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    Uri docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri));
    String path = null;
    int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        pickiT.getPath(docUri, version);
        // Uri is from unknown provider
}

@Override
public void PickiTonCompleteListener(String path, boolean wasDriveFile, boolean wasUnknownProvider, boolean wasSuccessful, String Reason) {
    Log.d("GraphActivity", "Path is not null");
    folder = new File(path);

    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yy_hh.mm", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    baseFilename = name + " " + timestamp;
    filename = "/" + folder.toString() + "/" + baseFilename + ".csv";

    if (filename == null) {
        Log.d("GraphAcitivty", "Filename is null");
    } else {
        Log.d("GraphAcitivty", "Filename is not null");
    }

    showSaveDialog();
}
```

Apparently `PickiTonCompleteListener` isn't even being called based on my print statements.  My activity does implement `PickiTCallbacks` but for some reason the callback isn't working.

I wonder, is there any solution out there that works?

Comment: "None of them seem to be able to get the file path from the URI." -- there is no file path. Use the `Uri` itself. For example, you can use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to get an `OutputStream` for use in writing content to the location identified by the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

when u want to insert a new document, the preferred way is to Use DownloadsFolder, on `api Q+(api 29)` there's a content provider that makes it easy .

this code will be compatible with all android version.

> Hint below android 10 u can use Document Folder ***for this solution*** but
> the recommended is to use `Downloads Folder`.

this is kotlin code convert it to java

**if this helped pls upvote**

```
fun example() {
      var filename = "yourFileName_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.pdf"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val uri = MediaStoreUtils.createDownloadUri(context, filename)

              if(uri == null){
                 return
               }

           try {
                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri, "w")?.use { outputStream ->
                   //write your file InputStream to the OutputStream
                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.printStackTrace().toString())
            }
        } else {
            val downloadsFolder =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)

            //re-generate the filename until we can confirm its uniqueness
            while (File(downloadsFolder, filename).exists()) {
                filename = generateFilename(type.extension)
            }

            val file = File(downloadsFolder, filename)

            try {
                file.outputStream().use { outputStream ->
                   //write your file InputStream to the OutputStream
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.printStackTrace().toString())
            }
        }
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun createDownloadUri(context: Context, filename: String): Uri? {
    val downloadsCollection =
        MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

        val newFileValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
        }

        // is better to execute off the main thread
        // run on Background Thread (IO)
        return context.contentResolver.insert(downloadsCollection, newFileValues)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Instead of using the `File` class I can use `DocumentFile` and do this:

```
final DocumentFile csvFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/csv", baseFileName);
if (csvFile != null) {
    out = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(csvFile.getUri());
}
```

Did not have to use the PickiT library to do this. For the PDF file, I use MIME type `application/pdf`.